# How can I use virtual environment in Visual Studio?

Tags: python, virtualenv

I activate the virtual environment in VSCode terminal:

[image]

and I check the pip list:

[image]

I can see the sklearn pip.
So I enter

```
import sklearn
```

in script but script can't find sklearn.

what is the problem?
Isn't the virtual environment activated just by typing in the terminal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's fine. Try to run this code and you won't get exceptions. To avoid this underscore `pip install autopep8` might help

Comment: terminal say "Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\project\test.py", line 1, in <module>
    import sklearn
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'sklearn'
(venv) PS C:\project> " TT

Comment: Did you start your code with venv activated?

Comment: yes i did, terminal show virtual environment name in front of output  TT

Comment: reinstall this library, update pip and try again. (venv) pip install sklearn